# How to select into record type in MySQL

Tags: mysql, oracle, recordtype

I have a table with several columns.  In Oracle I can just select this into a record type I define, and it is easy.   Does MySQL have this feature, or do I need to declare each variable?   My table is not large, but what if I had 50 columns?  Do I need to declare 50 variables?

```
  DECLARE orders_crs CURSOR FOR 
SELECT customer_id, first_name, last_name, email,
          company, address_1, address_2, address_3,
          city, state, province, country, zip_code,
          phone, order_number, order_date, quantity,
          item_number
FROM data_import;
```

Do I need to declare 18 variables for this??  Or can I fetch into some RECORDTYPE?

Comment: Mysql does not have recordtype and you will need to declare n variables.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a MySQL cursor selects data into a variables which you need to declare.

If you show the full code (purpose of the cursor), maybe there is a better way of doing things.

Comment: That is the cursor.  So, I have to select these fields into 18 variables?  What if my table was 50 columns?  Would I need 50 variables?   Doesn't MySQL have some type of RECORD TYPE I can declare or something, like Oracle?

Comment: RECORD TYPE is an Oracle feature, not part of standard SQL, so MySQL has not implemented such a feature. The reason for asking the full code (after the cursor) was just to see if the task could be done without a cursor.

Comment: It's unfortunate that oracle (which has had this and other great functionality for more than 20 years) has shown the world how good SQL can be and everyone else has responded with "We know SQL can be awesome but we prefer it to suck"